# How to access a .php file in a different directory using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, localhost

To start with, this question might already have an answer, but I have been searching all day, but I could not find a workout that helped me with my exact problem.

I am new to JavaScript and AJAX

I am trying out a web app, named `calendar.php` in the directory 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\aptana\testapp\`. 
This has a `script` named `calendar_script.js` in the directory 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\aptana\testapp\scripts\`.
The `calendar_script.js` has a function `getDetails()`

```
//--function to get the details from the server--
function getDetails(dateName){
     request = createRequest();

     if(request == null){
         alert("Undable to create request. Please Check Internet Connection or contact service Administrator.");
         return;
     }

     var url = "getEvents.php?dateID=" + escape(dateName);
     request.open("GET", url, true);
     request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
     request.send(null);
 }
```

The `createRequest()` function returns a request object.
The `getDetails()` function is called when there is a click event on the web page, which is a calendar.

The problem is with the `getEvents.php`. If it is placed in the directory 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\aptana\testapp\`
everything seems to work just fine, but if I move this file to another folder, which is
`C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\aptana\testapp\internals\` and try to access the file by creating a file path in my JavaScript code, it does not seem to work.
I tried doing

```
var base_url = window.location.origin + "\projects\aptana\testapp\internals\";
var url = base_url + "getEvents.php?dateID=" + escape(dateName);
request.open("GET", url, true);
```

it does not seem to work.
I also tried hard coding the entire file path : `C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\aptana\testapp\internals\` but it doesn't seem to work either.

I know I am doing a mistake and I am missing something. How can I solve this problem? Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the script in testapp/ and the php in testapp/internals/.
I think you have to use something like this:

```
var url = "internals/getEvents.php?dateID=" + escape(dateName);
request.open("GET", url, true);
```

Please note the `/` instead of `\`.

Comment: Yes, that should work, as far as I know, and I tried that too. But it is not working.

Comment: Have you used the slash instead of backslash? Because browsers (javascript) uses the unix convention so they use the slash and not the dos convention (backslash).

Comment: Can you open the network console in your browser and tell us what is the status of the request to the `getEvents.php`? 404? 403? 500?

Comment: @laserbeamer, yes I tried the forward slash, it doesn't work.

Comment: @gnucki, can you help me with how I should do that. I really don't know.

Comment: @SajibAcharya In firefox: open menue-> developer tools -> web console.
If you do not see any status try something like this in your code (to see if it is a 404 error (page not found)):
`request.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     console.log("Status is: " + request.status);
     displayDetails(request);
   }
}`

Comment: In Chrome `Tools -> Development tools -> Network` and look for the request to `getEvents.php` in the list of XHR.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `/` instead of `\`.
- Use relative instead of absolute paths (here your root directory is `C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\aptana\testapp`).

Your code:

```
var url = "internals/getEvents.php?dateID=" + escape(dateName);
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
request.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var base_url = window.location.origin + "\projects\aptana\testapp\internals\";
```

Into

```
var base_url = "projects/aptana/testapp/internals/";
```

Comment: Try add a slash before projects, so like this : `/projects/aptana/testapp/internals/`